# Mongoose connection to a MongoDB

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, frontend

I'm trying to connect to a mongodb with mongoose.createConnection in Angular 8, but I keep gettin this error:

```
mongoose.createConnection is not a function
```

Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteSegments } from '../mm-routing.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'elastic-search',
  templateUrl: './elastic-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./elastic-search.component.scss']
})
export class ElasticSearchComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

    open() {
      debugger;
      const mongoose = require('mongoose');

      const connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://Test/Test', { useNewUrlParser: true });

      var bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        title: String,
        author: String,
        description: String
      });

      var Book = mongoose.model("Book", bookSchema);

    }
}
```

I tried also with mongoose.connection but I get the same error in console.

Comment: what error can you show us the console output.

Comment: mongoose.createConnection is not a function, always this.

Comment: @RobNone, the calling of `createConnection` seems correct as per [mongoose code example](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/index.js#L418). Though you managed to get rid of the `console` error, we can't directly connect to `mongodb` from Angular code or any client side code per say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't directly connect from client code (Angular/React etc..) to DB.

Use any server side techniques like `Node` with `Express.js` or try with **Angular Universal SSR** as mentioned [here](https://morioh.com/p/cc795826322e).

Comment: I get always "createConnection is not a function" unfortunatly.

Comment: thanks for your help first of all. I'm trying to follow this tutorial to be more clear https://www.compose.com/articles/mongoosastic-the-power-of-mongodb-and-elasticsearch-together/